# valueBinding to content of array

Tags: javascript, sproutcore, sproutcore-controllers

I have this controller with a value.

```
App.xcontroller = SC.ArrayController.create({
   ...some code...
   array_values = [],
   ..more code...
})
```

Now i have somewhere in a view this valueBinding

```
valueBinding: 'App.xController.array_values',
```

When I change values in the array the view does not get updated. but when i do
the following in the controller:

```
var array_values = this.get('array_values');
...  adding / removing values to the array....  
  if (x_values.contains(x)){
    x_values.removeObject(x)
} else {
    x_values.pushObject(x);
};       
this.set('array_values', array_values.copy());
```

the binding works, the view gets updated. But ONLY with the copy().
I don't want to make a copy of the array, IMHO this is not efficient. I just want to
let the valueBinding know content has changed..

the x values are just a bunch of integers.

The reason i want this: I want to change the value key of a SegmentedItemView. I want to change the active buttons. But I do not know on forehand how many segmentedviews I have
so I thought i bind the value of every generated segemented view to some common array and change that common array to be able to change the active buttons on all of the segmented views. Since each button represents an item with an unique key it works fine. except that i have to copy the array each time.

Comment: what does 'do something' mean?  are you adding values into the array, or changing values on the objects in the array.

Comment: I'm adding and removing items from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. set the `content` property of the `xcontroller`
2. Bind to the `arrangedObjects` property of the `xcontroller`
3. You need to use KVO compliant methods on the array to get the bindings to fire.  The ArrayController itself has an `addObject` and `removeObject` methods.  Arrays in SC have been augmented with a `pushObject` method (among others), which is also KVO compliant.  So if you use the KVO methods the view should update.

The reason your view does not update is because you are bound to the array, but the array itself did not change.  When you do a copy, the array itself changes, so the bindings fire.

You might also want to try

`this.notifyPropertyChange('x_values');`

in the controller after you make the changes, but that is less preferable to using the built in KVO functionality.

Comment: I don't want to bind to the xcontroller and set its content because the xcontroller is an array of different objects than the one in array_values. I want to bind to the array_values array. Which i can turn into an ArrayController but now I get error messages:Object  has no method 'addObject' I believe the array controller wants to work with objects not with integers.

Comment: @stephan, you are playing with fire.  The proper way to do it is to have the ArrayController proxy the the array. Can you just set up another ArrayController?  After looking at your code again, im pretty certain that is why your pushObject/removeObject calls are not causing the binding to fire.  The other possibility is in how you set up your views...so do the views have bindings into the objects in the array?

Comment: @stephan, you can also use notifyPropertyChange; updated my answer.

Comment: I tried notifyPropertyChange before. did not work. Only copy worked.